# Need to delete cells in a column, if the values in an array and the value in another column exist

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am requesting help on VBA code in comparing an array in column N to text values in col F:L. If there is a match for each value from the array then color those cells red in col F:L  BUT, the other condition is the match is ONLY valid where there is a numeric value in one of the col R:X. Hence, "TSK" is only a valid matching value in col I(4). Thus I want to search for TSK in column I and color it red each time it occurs (33), and "MMM" in col G(2), and so on. col F:L and col R:X are relevant, data in R shows the occurrence of data in F, and so forth. I am trying to do this for each value in the array col N. Here is an example:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJe7S.png)
Thank you in advance if you can assist.

Comment: Title mentions deleting cells but that's not in the actual description of the problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with conditional formating.  In the example below, B3:D5 is selected and the formula shown is applied.

Note that C3 isn't highlighted because there's no number in I3

[image]